# Split String into words by multiple arguments for example both whitespace and "-"

Tags: java, regex, split

So I want to split a string using by space and "-".

For example, a sample string : "White-spaces are necessary"

The above String should be split into parts like "White", "space", "are", "necessary"

is this possible using split() method in Java.

Comment: Yes, split by `[- ]`.

Comment: `[-\\s]` (to match all whitespace - not just spaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The split method takes a String in the form of a regex.

Using regex character classes, we can say split on either space OR dashes.

the regex would be the following [ -].

Each character inside the brackets is a possible character to split on.
However, this would split groups of 2 or more white space characters as separate split items, so you would end up with empty array elements. To avoid this you can use:

[ -]+

More reading on regex character classes.

https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: So I would write it as : ```String.split("[ -]+")```, right?

Comment: Yup, but as Elliott pointed out "\\s" matches all whitespace not just spaces, so you may want to replace the space inside the brackets with \\s.